# Manage dashboard menu items base on user role in Next.js

Tags: authentication, next.js, next-auth

I used Next.js to manage the Authentication. After logging in, the user enters the dashboard, which has several menu items that are displayed to the user based on the user's access level.

Now, for security reasons, I want the list of dashboard menu items to be sent from the server side, and the user will not be able to see the total number of menus even by looking at the source code of the application.

For example:

If the user is logged in with the administrator role, the list of menu items:

```
Dashboard
servers
User management
Management of teams
```

If the user is logged in with the normal user role, the list of menu items:

```
Dashboard
```

What good solution would you suggest to manage this problem?